# Azure webapp to local server

Tags: azure, server, arduino, esp8266

I have a web application mounted on azure webapp is an api on node and I also need you to consume a service of a esp8266 wifi module but this module has a server with a local ip mounted, I need this azure app to connect to this local server of the Wi-Fi module.

NodeAPP in Azure   ->>> Modulo Wifi (ESP8266) in local Server

Comment: will this wifi module also be hosted on azure or it is running local on your machine?

Comment: local in my machine, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I have this kind of requirement, the easiest way to solve is by using Ngrok. Then, your web app will send data to ngrok, which will forward it to your local pc.

More info: https://ngrok.com/